# (Kubuntu 18.04) Discovery shows every installed application twice

Tags: kubuntu, kde, appmenu

today I realized that my Discovery application manager is stating every single entry in my "Installed" list twice. Any idea why and how I can fix it? (See screenshot)

- KDE Plasma Version: 5.12.6
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.44.0
- Qt Version: 5.9.5
- Kernel Version: 4.15.0-29 64 bit

[image]

Cheers
Ruphus